# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp - Parameters - Conflict

Tags: android, eclipse, android-async-http

I wanted to import "latest.jason" from "OpenExchange rates" for latest currency rates.

But when I write "AsyncHttpClient" it creates the following "Un-Implemented Class":

```
@Override
        public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

But I wanted this- (to run)

```
            public void onSuccess(String arg2) {
            Log.i("MYFIRSTAPP" , "HTTP Successs");
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(arg2);
                JSONObject ratesObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rates");
                Double gbpRate = ratesObject.getDouble("GBP");
                Double eurRate = ratesObject.getDouble("EUR");
                Log.i("MYFIRSTAPP", "GBP" +gbpRate);
                Log.i("MYFIRSTAPP", "EUR" +eurRate);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

The problem I''m getting is: 
The onSuccess is taking " int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2 " as the parameters...

but i wanted - " String arg2 "

Comment: can you please provide more code or full code ?

Comment: which interface have you implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] header, byte[] content,
                Throwable error)
        {
            // show error messages here
           super.onFailure(statusCode, error, content);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] header, byte[] content)
        {
            if (statusCode == 200)
            {
                try
                {
                    //convert byte[] to string.
                    String contentStr = content.toString();

                    Log.i("Tag", "content" + URL + " " + contentStr );
                    
                    //String to JSONObject.
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(contentStr );
                    JSONObject ratesObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rates");
                    Double gbpRate = ratesObject.getDouble("GBP");
                    Double eurRate = ratesObject.getDouble("EUR");
                    Log.i("MYFIRSTAPP", "GBP" + gbpRate);
                    Log.i("MYFIRSTAPP", "EUR" + eurRate);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.toString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // show network error toast here;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many variants of `onSuccess` and `onFailure` methods in [AsyncHttpResponseHandler](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler.html) and its subclasses.

Most suitable for handling JSON data is in [JsonHttpResponseHandler](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.html)

Comment: There is only one variant of onSuccess() and one variant of onFailure() in AsyncHttpResponseHandler.

Comment: Agree. Now, there is only one variant of `onSuccess` and `onFailure` in version 1.4.9 (in AsyncHttpResponseHandler)